# Scrolling Performance issue with UItextView with large NSAttributedString

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview, nsattributedstring, nslayoutmanager

I am working on text editor for an app. I am using UITextView

See the sample code to load text view.

```
// Read text from file (around 300k - 400k words)
NSError *error = nil;
NSString *contentOfFile = [[NSString alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"17254" ofType:@"txt"]
                                                          encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding
                                                             error:&error];

// Attributes for text
UIFont *font = [UIFont fontWithName:@"Baskerville" size:36.0f];
NSMutableParagraphStyle *paragraphStyle = [[NSMutableParagraphStyle alloc] init];
paragraphStyle.alignment = NSTextAlignmentJustified;

NSDictionary *attributes = [[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjectsAndKeys:font, NSFontAttributeName,
                            [UIColor blackColor], NSForegroundColorAttributeName,
                            paragraphStyle, NSParagraphStyleAttributeName, nil];


// Create attributed string
NSAttributedString *attributedString = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:contentOfFile attributes:attributes];

// Assign to text view
self.textView.attributedText = attributedString;
```

The size of text is around 400k words.

I am facing the following issues.

- Scrolling of text becomes too slow as i scroll down and some time app crashes due to memory issue. What i think iOS is saving the rendered text image in its memory when textview is scrolled down, but when i scroll up to top it releases the memory.
- If i tap "Select All" it takes too much time to select the text and after text selection the scrolling becomes poor and some times app crashes due to memory issue because its memory increases. I think iOS generates the image of complete text(as if its visible to user) in its memory and then selects the complete text and retain its image until selection is finished. After selection is finished memory retained by app drops.

The other way of displaying the large text is to use the multiple textviews and assign the text to visible textview only like UITableView, but this will increase the complexity as i have to recount the number of textviews required on each textChanged delegate call of layoutManager of UItextView.

Any body has idea how to display large attributed text in UITextView with better performance.

Any guess how iPages app is working, because it display text when the area is in visible range.

Comment: Pages uses a completely custom view... If you're just showing text, you could use a `UIWebView`... Just wrap your text in some HTML tags for formatting, and then display it like that

Comment: Its an editor. User can edit font, color and alignment. Can add page breaks and some other options as well.

Answer (score -2):

You should not load entire text directly. You should load the text which is twice as much as the textview capacity.

Now track the scroll event and modify the string dynamically.

Comment: I have the same problem. May you specify your answer more.

Comment: Please make your answer more clear with an example - at the moment it is a bit confusing